# Libgdx animation problems

Tags: java, android, kotlin, libgdx, box2d

I am making a game via libgdx for android phone. When I add explosion annimations in the game, after 10 munits later the game is stretching  and  I am getting this error messages which is below. After 20 munits the game crash and I am getting another error messages in android studio. What is this. Thank you so much.

The first error messages

```
 E/IMGSRV: :0: PVRPMapKMem: mmap(2) failed: Mapping handle=0x55d: strerror returns no value.
        :0: PVRSRVAllocDeviceMem : PVRPMapKMem failed for buffer
        :0: PVRPMapKMem: mmap(2) failed: Mapping handle=0x5b1: strerror returns no value.
        :0: PVRSRVAllocDeviceMem : PVRPMapKMem failed for buffer
```

The second messages.

```
A/libc: malloc size: 67108864
    malloc size: 67108864
E/IMGSRV: :0: PVRPMapKMem: mmap(2) failed: Mapping handle=0x40f: strerror returns no value.
    :0: PVRSRVAllocDeviceMem : PVRPMapKMem failed for buffer 
A/libc: malloc size: 1440000
W/dalvikvm: threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x430f2140)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 20166
    Process: com.mygdx.game, PID: 12106
    com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: assets/animations/explosion.png
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:148)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.TextureData$Factory.loadFromFile(TextureData.java:98)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:122)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:118)
E/AndroidGraphics: waiting for pause synchronization took too long; assuming deadlock and killing
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 12106 SIG: 9
```

Comment: The error seems to be that no memory could be allocated when trying to load a texture. Do you reload the texture every time you want to use it? This could cause the memory problems. Using an [AssetManager](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets) might fix the problem, because it will reduce the memory needed by your application.

Comment: If you create a `new Texture` in your game loop, you are loading duplicate copies on every frame of animation and leaking all the old copies.

Comment: In case you want to free Texture from memory, then use dispose method (you should use this method with anything that supports it after you won't be using that object anymore - https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Disposable.html )